# How to get Chrome to respond to Windows 10 high contrast mode using javascript/typescript in a React app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, accessibility, high-contrast

I'm looking for a simple way to detect if the user's system is in high contrast mode or not using javascript/typescript within a react app.

Is there a public method available in a library somewhere?

These stackoverflow posts don't give me what I'm looking for, which is a method from an import:

[Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411712/detect-if-high-contrast-is-enabled-in-android-accessibility-settings)

[How to detect MAC OS inverted color mode in JavaScript / CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104388/how-to-detect-mac-os-inverted-color-mode-in-javascript-css)

[How do I detect if a user has Mac OS high contrast accessibility settings enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964264/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-mac-os-high-contrast-accessibility-settings-enable)

**EDIT**: I intend to be able to differentiate between black on white and white on black mode

**EDIT**: Here is what I've tried but it doesn't get applied in Chrome

```
/* Targets displays using the Windows’ "High Contrast Black" theme: */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: white-on-black) {
    .targetClass {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }
 }

/* Targets displays using the Windows’ "High Contrast White" theme: */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: black-on-white) {
    .targetClass {
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
    }
 }
```

Comment: [How to detect if high contrast is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281873/5587356)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492220/detect-high-contrast-extension-use-in-chrome-browser

Comment: Is Chrome the only browser your question applies to?

Comment: FYI: the `-ms-high-contrast` media queries work for IE and Edge Legacy only.

Comment: I see I now understand. I need something for chrome as well then

Comment: Yeah, Chrome does it's own thing with its [High Contrast extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en). It doesn't respond to Windows 10 High Contrast.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, please feel free to write all of your comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is what I've tried but it doesn't get applied in Chrome

#### How to get Chrome to respond to Windows 10 High Contrast mode:

Chrome does its own thing with its [High Contrast Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en-GB). This extension doesn't respond to Windows 10 High Contrast mode!

Chrome also won't respond to the `ms-high-contrast` media queries, which are for IE and Edge Legacy only.

However, you can detect if Chrome's High Contrast Extension is enabled via TypeScript like this:

```js
const htmlTag: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
const isUsingChromeHighContrastExtension: boolean =
    htmlTag.getAttribute('hc') !== null;
```

Now you have a boolean, `isUsingChromeHighContrastExtension`, that you can use to adjust your styling based on whether the extension is enabled.

Note that Chrome's High Contrast Extension doesn't have a black on white or a white on black setting, but it does have a variety of other options that some visually impaired people benefit from.

#### Related:

[How to detect if high contrast is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281873/5587356) for TypeScript detection of high contrast in other browsers/platforms as well.

[Targeting Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57330701/5587356)